# How do I import a js file in Coffeescript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, webpacker

I'm currently trying to [Code Split](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) & [Lazy Load](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) the javascript in my huge app and got to a point where I have to lazy import a `.js` file from a `.coffee` file.

In a normal `.js` file I do something like this:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "vnd-forms" */ 'js/vendor/forms').then(() => {
  do_something
});
```

I knew writing the same thing in `.coffee` will fail, but here it is:

```
error: regular expressions cannot begin with *
import(/* webpackChunkName: "vnd-forms" */ 'js/vendor/forms').then(() ->
```

**How can I lazy import that file in `.coffee` files?**

I'm using Webpacker 4.3, Rails 4.2. We are migrating from coffeescript to es6 in baby steps since the codebase is humongous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out coffeescript has these backticks :)

```
`import(/* webpackChunkName: "vnd-forms" */ 'js/vendor/forms')`.then(() ->
  do_something
)
```

Now everything loads properly!